# What to do if angular can't save the app.component.html file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I get this error if I change anything in the `app.component.html` file everytime?

Can anyone help me please?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw1sj.png

I tried to run it as a `sudo`(I'm on mac) already and got this error message then.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the file seems to be in a synced directory ?